# enviar Correo mediante SES, Lambda y Node js no Funciona

Tags: nodejs, lambda

estoy intentando enviar un correo desde Lambda con una cuenta autenticada previamente en SES mediante nodejs usando Nodemailer pero no obtengo ningun registro de error, ni tampoco se realiza el envio del correo, este es el proceso que estoy realizando para hacerlo:

```
module.exports.eviarCorreoPrueba = (event, context, callback) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

  console.log('inicia envio de correos');

    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        //pool: true,
        host: 'host',
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        auth: {
            user: 'user',
            pass: 'key',

        }
    });

    console.log('se crea transporte ');

    var mailOptions = {

        from: 'email@prueba.mx',
        to: 'email@prueba.mx',
        subject: 'Prueba Lambda',

        html: 'hello World'
    };

    console.log('se asignan las opciones de correo');
    console.log('inicia envio de correo');

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
        if (error) {
            callback(null, {
              statusCode: 200,
              body: JSON.stringify({
                input: 'not send'
              })
            })
        }else {
            console.log('Email sent');
            console.log('correo finalizado');

        }
    });
    console.log('funcion finalizada');
};
```

Comment: Este es el resutado que obtengo en los Logs: 15:40:23.440 e78273c8-5497-416d-b076-700cbd2fb63b inicia envio de correos
15:40:23.443 e78273c8-5497-416d-b076-700cbd2fb63b se crea transporte 
15:40:23.443 e78273c8-5497-416d-b076-700cbd2fb63b se asignan las opciones de correo
15:40:23.443 e78273c8-5497-416d-b076-700cbd2fb63b inicia envio de correo
15:40:23.443 e78273c8-5497-416d-b076-700cbd2fb63b entrando a try catch
15:40:23.450 e78273c8-5497-416d-b076-700cbd2fb63b saliendo del try catch
15:40:23.450 e78273c8-5497-416d-b076-700cbd2fb63b funcion finalizada

Comment: ¿Cuales son los valores de `error` e `info` en la llamada al callback?

Comment: revisando la documentacion de nodemailer te falta agregar codigo, este link es la docs oficial de como usar SES con nodemailer https://nodemailer.com/transports/ses/